# Excel UDF precedence: UDF in add-in takes precedence over UDF in workbook itself

Tags: vba, excel

I have my own Excel User Defined Functions (UDFs) which are in an Excel add-in file (.xlam) attached to my Excel.

When I deliver workbooks to clients I copy the necessary VBA modules into the final workbook (let's call this the "workbook+VBA").

If I disconnect my master add-in from Excel (via the Excel VBA Add-ins dialogue) and then open the "workbook+VBA" then everything is OK.

However, if my master add-in is still connected to Excel, then Excel will give precedence to linking to the UDF in the add-in rather than the same named UDF included in the "workbook+VBA" itself.

If I save the "workbook+VBA", disconnect the master add-in and then reopen the "workbook+VBA", then all the Excel cell formulas calling the UDFs will be prefixed with the full path to my master add-in .xlam file.

This behavior was introduced with Excel 2007. Prior to this Excel gave precedence to the UDF included in the workbook itself above the same named UDF in an add-in.

Is there any way in which this order of precedence can be reversed so that the workbook itself takes precedence as UDF source?

Searches for this topic have been unsuccessful.